# Getting the id of each tr not working

Tags: javascript, html

My code for getting the id of the tr in a table is not working.

I retrieved the data of the table from mysql db and populated the table. But for the better and easy to read, let's just assume I have this table here:

```
<table>
   <tr id = "1" class = "tablerow">
      <td> Your awesome </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id = "2" class = "tablerow">
      <td> Your great </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id = "3" class = "tablerow">
      <td> Your amazing </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and also have this js:

```
    $(".tablerow").click(function(event){
        var id = this.id;
        alert(id);
    });
```

but it's not working, it just alert's an empty string. Why?

Comment: which jquery version you are using? Check this fiddle. Your code works perfectly here: https://jsfiddle.net/197du8fj/

Comment: I agree with @xyz  but maybe it happened to have a conflict with his jquery or he forgot to declare it. what do you think?

Comment: @Makudex: Yeah, I guess, he did not declared id attribute for the `tr`'s. Apart from that it should work fine.

Comment: @xyz: Yeah i think so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, hope it may help you:

```
$(document).on("click",".tablerow",function(event){ 
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
});
```

If it still not working try to check also if your jquery is declared. like this one: `<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`

Enjoy!

Comment: This code works very well. Thank you sir!  I've been stuck with this for an hour. Thank you so much..

Comment: @DEV'1 What Makudex is doing in his answer is what's called a "delegate bind", which basically means that he hooks up a click listener on a higher level element than the one clicked and waiting for the click event to bubble up and checking where it originated from. However, it is better for performance to hook up the delegate as close as possible in the hierarchy to the actual element, so that the click event need not bubble as far. I assume that you're ajax-loading this data somehow, and I'd suggest hooking up the event on the closest parent that is present on pageload, instead of `document`.

Answer (score 1):

try to change your code to next

```
$(".tablerow").click(function(event){
    var clicked = $(this),
        id;
    if(clicked.attr('id')){
        id = clicked.attr('id');          
    }
    else{
        id = clicked.parent().attr('id');
    }

    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Why complicate things? if there's more shorter code?

Comment: Thank you sir.. Thank you for this one!

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
$(".tablerow").click(function(event){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
    });
```

**Explaination**

When you are trying to access `this` inside the click event you are only accessing the element but you want to select that DOM Element, so you should use

```
$(this) //it will select the DOM element as a Jquery object.
```

Then you should use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method of Jquery to access attributes of the particular DOM Element.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have only one table on your page:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[index].id;
```

Preferably though, you'd give your table a id, though, and get your row like this:

```
<table id="tableId">
   <tr id = "1" class = "tablerow">
      <td> Your awesome </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id = "2" class = "tablerow">
      <td> Your great </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id = "3" class = "tablerow">
      <td> Your amazing </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

js code:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
var row = table.rows[index];
console.log(row.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use:

```
$(".tablerow").click(function(e) {

   var proxy = this.id;
   id = this.id;
   console.log(id);

});
```